# How can I get an edited image with AssetLibrary

Tags: iphone, ios, image

The problem is that I can get an image with AssetLibrary, but not an edited image.

First I use the iPhone's app camera to take a photo, then I edit the photo, just cut down the photo.

And in my app, I want to get the edited image.

if I use the UIImagePickerController delegate method

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
```

I can get the edited image with the image.

But if I use the the method

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
```

and use the info to get a referenceURL,

with the referenceURL I can use AssetLibrary to get an image.

The point is that the image is always the original image before editing, not the image I have edited.

Answer (score 0):

You can edited image like this -

```
UIImage* image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
```

Comment: Thanks, I just want to get the edited image with ALAssetsLibrary. the code is 

NSURL *referenceURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];

ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    [library assetForURL:referenceURL resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
        ...
} failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
        ...
    }];

sorry for that I don't know how to edit the format.

Comment: if you use UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL then it will never give you edited image as document says - "After the user edits a picked item—such as by cropping an image or trimming a movie—the URL continues to point to the original version of the picked item."

Comment: is there any specific reason that you are using asset library for getting image ?

Comment: Oh, I know it. Thank you very much. And is there any way to know whether the image has been edited. [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] return nil;

Comment: [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"] return the edited image if the image was edited.
The reason why I use ALAssetLibrary is that the base code uses ALAssetLibrary, so you know the reason, hehe.